# OpenCV - Directly copying matrix multiplication result to a subset of another matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, subset, memory-efficient

I try to directly copying matrix multiplication result to a subset of another matrix:

```
cv::Mat a,b,c;
//fill matrices a and b and set matrix c to correct size
cv::Mat ab=a*b;
ab.copyTo(c(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)));
```

isn' it possible to directly copy the result to matrix c like e.g. (I know this doesn't work):

```
(a*b).copyTo(c(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)));
//or 
c(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)).setTo(a*b);
```

Wouldn't it be more efficient?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? seems good to me. You're creating a new object using `a * b`, if you use it directly or store it in a temporary variable, it's almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cv::Mat subC = c(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3));
subC = a*b;
```

No copying here.

Or more succinctly:

```
c(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)) = a*b;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!<\br> `c(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)) = a*b;` works fine!